# Symfony need cache:clear too often

Tags: symfony

I started learn Symfony 3 days ago and have the problem with cache or something else.

The first I have `RegisterController`:

```
public function index(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $user = $form->getData();

        $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword()));

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('register/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Its working fine. But when I write before

```php
$user = new User();
```

this line `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted("ROLE_ADMIN");` - I have access "Access Denied" its okay because I have another role.

But when I delete this line code `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted("ROLE_ADMIN");` and refresh the page I have screen:

> This page isn’t working
>   symfony.local didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

and I can't access this page anymore. I have to clear the cache:

```sh
php bin/console cache:clear
```

or restart apache.

Can you tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you in dev mode?  It could be your Apache configuration.  Have you tried using the symfony web server for development?

Comment: Now I used a symfony server and when I did the same I had 

# unable to fetch the response from the backend: unexpected EOF

Comment: I'm afraid that there is just not enough info to provide useful help.  Plus you are using a very old version of Symfony.  Presumably for legacy purposes.  If you could post your app to github then I would take a look.

Comment: I started learn Symfony, 3 days go :) sorry for my description. I used Symfony 5, MAC OS. Now I see when I used dd function I have the same problems.

Comment: I create a empty application: symfony new my_project_name --full and run the server symfony server:start and use dd function and have the same problem.

Example dd('asd') and change "asd" to "oo" and get screen unable to fetch the response from the backend: unexpected EOF

Answer (score 0):

I have problem with PHP version: 7.4.0 and php fpm . I do update the php to 7.4.3 and now is okay. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score -1):

Symfony can be configured for different [environments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-environments) and those environments can change how Symfony behaves. If you a running a production environment, Symfony will perform a lot of caching to increase the speed which it serves pages to your guests. If you are in DEV mode it will reload most code changes each time you run it.

However web servers / php can also cache your files as well. If you are in DEV mode in Symfony, and still having this problem check the caching settings in the php.ini file.

Comment: I am on dev mode. 
I run on symfony web server now.

When I use dd function and change the inside string I have the same problem.